# Does ETOPS apply to Part 125 operations?

Tags: faa-regulations, etops

Does ETOPS apply to aircraft operated under Part 125? I see ETOPS mentioned in Part 121 Appendix P and Part 25 Appendix K, but it would appear that ETOPS wouldn't apply to Part 125 operated aircraft?

Comment: Do you  mean Part 125 "Operations?" ETOPs, in the context you are asking, applies to the operation.

Comment: Yes I do mean Part 125 Operations, and edited the question to clarify. However the question was further edited by the moderator (I assume) and doesn't show my edits.

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing FAR Part 125, I concur with the last sentence in the question "It would appear that ETOPS wouldn't apply to Part 125 operated aircraft."

Since there are no references associated with ETOPs contained in the regulation, ETOP's criteria, limitations, operating specifications, etc. do not apply when conducting "**operations**" in aircraft under Part 125.

Comment: While ETOPS provisions may not be given for §125 operations, they are for §135 operations.

Comment: @j Walters-The question acknowledged that ETOPs applied to Part 121 operations, but "It would appear that ETOPs would not apply to Part 125 operations."  My (original) answer confirmed that ETOPs did in fact apply to Part 121 operations, but not to Part 125 operations.  Apparently, because I did not further imagine what question the questioner would have regarding Part 135 operations, I did not address that.  Of course ETOPs has been available for Part 135 operations for about 10 years (approximately).  I've changed my answer eliminating any reference to Part 121.

Comment: Your comments make for a better answer than your “answer” - which as written carries the slight authority of “somebody on the internet said so” and no more. Can you beef up your answer with explanation and/or a reference, maybe incorporating the ideas (applicable to operations rather than aircraft, etc) of your comments? I suspect you have the background to provide an enlightening answer here, but the one-liner isn’t it.

Comment: @Ralph J - I don't disagree with your comment.  However, In my comment (below the question) I inquired exactly as you suggest regarding ETOPs applying to an aircraft or operations.  Receiving no answer, I merely confirmed what the questioner had apparently already discovered. Specifically, there is nothing in Part 125 that is associated with ETOPS.  I can't really reference a negative (if it's not part of the regulation, there is no reference to it in the regulation).  I will expand my answer and include that.